# Change the vertical divide colour in SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

Can anyone please tell me how to change the vertical divide colour (between master and detail views) in a split view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't?!?!

You could add your UISplitViewController as a childviewcontroller to another view controller and change that controller's view's background color and see if that solves your problem...

You could also create your own view controller subclass that behaves like a splitviewcontroller and draw a different color between the two.

or draw a line where you think your splitviewcontroller's divider is...

I would recommend not doing it in the first place...